# Laravel Avored admin 403 forbidden, can't access admin page in avored package

Tags: php, laravel

Cannot access avored-admin. Gives me forbidden error! (https://ibb.co/W6tpY9M)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.
I was accessing the wrong page for admin panel.
The correct url for admin page was http:\yoursite.com/admin